# two phase locking and a contest question?

Tags: database-theory, databases, deadlocks

In 2PL (two phase locking), what advantage(s) does the rigorous model have over  the strict model?

> I) There is no advantage over the strict model.
>
> II) In contrast to the strict model, it guarantees that starvation
>   cannot occur.
>
> III) In contrast to the strict model, it guarantees that deadlock
>   cannot occur.
>
> IV) In contrast to the strict model, there is no need to predict data
>   needed in the future.

My TA says all of the above are false and the question is wrong. I am a bit confused. Can someone clarify for me why these are false. the answer sheet say IV is true !!

Comment: [Also posted on CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31329/5038).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.